# Каталог товаров на любой open source CMS

Tags: joomla, wordpress

Здравствуйте, приспичило быстро сделать простой каталог товаров на какой-нибудь бесплатной CMS, типа wordpress или joomla. Сам искал, но постоянно натыкаюсь на какие-нибудь здоровенные woocommece или virtuemart. Обязателен следующий функционал:

1. категории/подкатегории товаров и их вывод с их описанием и товарами (в некоторых каталогах и такого нет)
2. можно добавить атрибут товара любого типа
3. к товару можно добавить несколько изображений
4. добавлять seo теги к товару и категории, и никаких дублей страниц
5. сортировка товаров по атрибутам

Что посоветуете?

P.S.: До этого решил попробовать yupe, так как он сделан на любимом yii, но там каталог товаров никакой (много придется пилить руками, что не заложено в сроки) и офф. форум не подает признаков жизни.

Comment: А корзина например предполагается? А-то может проще смотреть на это не как на каталог товаров.

В принципе я вижу как эти пять пунктов можно реализовать в WP вообще без плагинов (произвольные поля, возможно пользовательские таксономии (с просони не соображу нужны-ли они тут), поиск по произвольным полям через sphinx, если нагрузка будет высока).

Ещё есть: OpenCart — CMS, ориентированная на создание интернет-магазинов. GPL, MVC, PHP

Comment: В моем случае корзина не нужна

Comment: Может будет полезно http://wpmag.ru/2014/rabota-s-proizvolnyimi-polyami-v-wp_query/

Вроде голый вордпресс покрывает всё что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен интернет-магазин на yii2 - попробуйте [DotPlant2](https://github.com/devgroup-ru/dotplant2)